# Building regular expression with dot

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace dot with blank-space if surrounded/preceded/followed by non-digits, and do nothing if surrounded/preceded/followed by digits.

For example, String "I ran 4.4 Km. Total 2 times." will become "I ran 4.4 Km Total 2 times "

I need help in building this regular expression. I am using this:

```
string.replaceAll("[D].", "[D]")
```

and, getting numerous dots only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaheads and lookbehinds like

```
System.out.println(Str.replaceAll("(?<=\\D)\\.(?=\\D|$)", ""));
```

*Regex Explanation*

```
(?<=\\D) #Lookbehind to match non-digit
\\. #Match . literally
(?=\\D|$) #Lookahead to match non-digit or end of string
```